How do I learn about Space Mining and the Space Industry?
So I'm a very spirited entrepreneurial college student whose lacked some direction in what I want to do with my Computer Science degree once I graduate. I've lived on the Space Coast my whole life, and I've always been enamored by space, so seeing rocket launches every day has gotten me interested in how I can get into the industry as I approach graduation. After seeing the advances in private space infrastructure like SpaceX and Blue Origin, especially with the catching of the Starship booster, I'm predicting (and truly believe) that cost to orbit will be significantly cheaper, by half of its current cost, in the next 3 years, if not earlier.
I've come to the idea of starting something in the Space Mining, since it's only a natural technological progression that we collect resources from asteroids, lunar bodies, etc. I just wanted to know where can I start? Totally ambitious I know, but it gives me the urgency to want to learn more about the space industry, since regardless of whether I succeed or not, I think the skills of embedded systems, robotics and AI are going to be super valuable in the next coming decades. I think this is something I can truly immerse myself in and get passionate about it, because it brings software and hardware together. I really think the skills I'll learn here will be more valuable than any other booming field currently in tech. LLM Research for example, I think that'll crash soon since they don't generate any profit, but who knows!

(1) Asteroids are sooooooooooo much further away than you think they are.  (2) Space in general is, likewise, sooooooooooo much harder than you think it is.

@RonJohn Space may be hard, but still not nearly as hard as an asteroid. ;)

I think that others will post answers with specific information, but since you're a new user to Stack Exchange asking your first question, I'll also add the following:
Welcome to Space Exploration SE!

...I just wanted to know where can I start?"

You can start by simply clicking on the mining and asteroid-mining tags you've added under your question, and then reading the questions, their answers, and the materials linked on those pages. That's one of the main raisons d'etre for the Stack Exchange ecosystem - to make a searchable database of information on a wide variety of specific topics.
In the parallel meta site for Space SE, also see:

Educational resources to accompany Space Exploration
Resources and references on the topic of space exploration


While asteroid mining might be a bit far off, in-situ resource utilization (ISRU) is not, and NASA has an active program on it!
ISRU is the process of utilizing materials available in space which often includes space mining.
Searching nasa in-situ on youtube turns up a couple of presentations by NASA
Searching on google also turns up a couple of 20+ page reports/presentations on NASA's ISRU program, e.g. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20220008799/downloads/NASA%20ISRU%20Plans_Sanders_COSPAR-Final.pdf
Also checkout NASA's ISRU robot
In 2021, NASA hosted the NASA Space Robotics Challenge, Phase 2 which simulates a lunar ISRU operation and requires teams to develop the software for controlling the robots.  The winning team Olympus Mons also kindly made their summary available.
In terms of industry, aside from the big players in space (SpaceX, BlueOrigin, Sierra Space, etc.), I know of OffWorld which is a company explicitly targetting space mining, though current operations are earthbound (obviously).
Since you are a CS graduate, I'd also recommend taking a look at SpaceROS, a robotics middleware framework targeting space robotics operations, based on the popular (earthbound) robotics middlware framework ROS
All this should keep you busy for a while, happy mining :)
